# Compiling learning_image_transport tutorial on fuerte/catkin

Tags: catkin, ros-fuerte

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I try to build the tutorial package learning_image_transport on fuerte/catkin running debian/sid.
I had to install the following packages: pluginlib, opencv2,cv_bridge,image_transport.

I successfully created the package using the following commands:

`roscd`

roscreate-pkg learning_image_transport image_transport opencv2 cv_bridge

rospack profile

But the compilation fails:

cmake learning_image_transport

[rosbuild] Building package learning_image_transport

[rosbuild] Cached build flags older than manifests; calling rospack to get flags

Failed to invoke /opt/ros/fuerte/bin/rospack cflags-only-I;--deps-only learning_image_transport

Package pluginlib was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `pluginlib.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable

No package 'pluginlib' found

CMake Error at /opt/ros/fuerte/share/ros/core/rosbuild/public.cmake:129 (message):

Failed to invoke rospack to get compile flags for package
'learning_image_transport'.  Look above for errors from rospack itself.
Aborting.  Please fix the broken dependency!

Call Stack (most recent call first):
/opt/ros/fuerte/share/ros/core/rosbuild/public.cmake:227 (rosbuild_invoke_rospack)
CMakeLists.txt:12 (rosbuild_init)

-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!

The file pluginlib.pc is in /opt/ros/fuerte/share/pluginlib/build/CMakeFiles
How can I add it ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/42825/compiling-learning_image_transport-tutorial-on-fuerte/catkin/) by [Fabien R](https://answers.ros.org/users/2975/fabien-r/) on ROS Answers with karma: 90 on 2012-09-02

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Fabien R](https://answers.ros.org/users/2975/fabien-r/) on 2012-09-08**:
@joq: The result is the same with rosmake: [ rosmake ] All 25 linesmage_transport: 0.8 ec                                                             [rosbuild] Building package image_transport
No package 'pluginlib' found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

image_transport is not fully migrated to catkin yet since a few dependencies such as pluginlib still needs to be catkinized. Building the package with rosbuild should work.

---

Originally posted by [jkammerl](https://answers.ros.org/users/3073/jkammerl/) with karma: 146 on 2012-09-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1